# Double Dot table qualifier

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking at a new database schema developed by an external vendor.  There are two databases:

```
Database1
Database2
```

They have sent me an SQL statement that joins tables between the two databases.  There are places where they have used a double dot notation.  I have never seen this before.  Please see the SQL statement below (this is not the statement they sent me):

```
select * from database2..Person
```

The statement above is run from database1.  Why does it have two dots? If I remove one of the dots then the query does not run.

I have done some Googling and came across this: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic585446-338-1.aspx.  This suggests it is referring to the schema.  However:

1. The schema is empty in the sql statement i.e. there is no text in between the two dots.
2. The Person table is part of the dbo schema in database2.

Comment: One of the comments in your link mentions that `database2..Person` is equivalent to `database2.dbo.Person`.  Have you tested both of these expressions in your console?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Thanks to this dot, the default schema (dbo) is choosen for your query.

When you have two databases it is required to give the full path to the table.
If we have:
Database1 schema: dbo, guest table dbo.A, guest: A
Database2 schema: dbo, guest table dbo.B, guest: B

if we create select statement like:

> select * from Database2..B

We are selecting data from dbo.B table
IF we would like to specify schema we need to refer as

```
select * from Database2.schemaname.tablename
```

EDIT:
As colleagues pointed out, the default schema can be changed in database, however in this particular example it seems to be dbo :)

Comment: Note that a user's default schema might not be 'dbo'.

Comment: Note that the default schema isn't necessarily `dbo`, but in this instance it probably is. The default schema can be changed (eg `alter user <user-name> with default_schema = <new-schema>`.

Comment: Thanks Chalky.  I think that clarifies it.

Answer (score 22):

This is a database schema. Full three-part name of a table is:

```
databasename.schemaname.tablename
```

For a default schema of the user, you can also omit the schema name:

```
databasename..tablename
```

You can also specify a linked server name:

```
servername.databasename.schemaname.tablename
```

You can read more about using identifiers as table names on [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187879%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)