# what does "select * from a..c" means

Tags: sql

What does double dot inside the table name in the following statement mean?

```
select * from a..c
```

Comment: please provide give some example with reference to your question and database you are using

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Double Dot table qualifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786049/double-dot-table-qualifier)

Comment: `a..c` is invalid standard SQL. Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the fisrt part (a) is the Database name and the (..) indicates the default schema (dbo) and c is the table name so:-

```
    select * from a..c
```

is equal to

```
    select * from a.dbo.c
```

Comment: if this helped you please mark as answer @Ashutosh Mishra

Answer (score 0):

First variable indicate database name of your server and second variable 
    indicate table name of your mentioned database.

```
SELECT * FROM [DataBaseName]..[Table_Name]
```