# SQL: Pull List Of Tables From Specified Database While Attached To Another

Tags: c#, sql

I am facing a peculiar issue with loading a list of tables from a specific database (well rather a group of databases) while attached to the master database. Currently my query loads all of the databases on the server, then loops through those databases sending information back to the client via `RAISERROR`. As this loop is executing I need a nested loop to load all of the tables for the current database for later transmission as a `SELECT` once the query has completed. The issue I'm running into is that this will be executed as a single query inside of C# code. Ideally I would like to load everything in SQL and return it to the client for processing. For example:

```
WHILE (@dbLoop < @dbCount) BEGIN
     -- Do cool things and send details back to client.
     SET @dbName = (SELECT _name FROM dbTemp WHERE _id = @dbLoop);
     -- USE [@dbName]
     -- Get a count of the tables from info schema on the newly specified database.
     WHILE (@tableLoop < @tableCount) BEGIN
          -- USE [@dbName]
          -- Do super cool things and load tables from info schema.
          SET @tableLoop += 1;
     END

     SET @dbLoop += 1;
END

-- Return the list of tables from all databases to the client for use with SQLDataAdapter.
SELECT * FROM tableTemp;
```

This topic is pretty straight forward; I just need a way to access tables in a specified database (preferably by name) without having to change the connection on the `SqlConnection` object, and without having to have a loop inside of my C# code to process the same query on each database on the C# side. It would be more efficient to load everything in SQL and send it back to the application. Any help that can be provided on this would be great!

Thanks,
Jamie

Comment: Why don't you write a stored procedure?

Comment: Thought about that and was told we don't use any stored procedures aside from the ones provided by Microsoft because they present a security risk. Also, in case someone also asks why I don't use a cursor query, our DBA doesn't allow cursor queries unless the can be justified as a dire need.

Comment: @lxxtacoxxl -- actually it is the reverse -- SPs are much more secure.

Comment: Hrm, well I was lied to :) Either way, they won't let me use a stored procedure so I have to do it with a query.

Comment: Couldn't you just use USE? (no pun intended) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/use-transact-sql

Comment: Because the database name is a variable inside of SQL, if this was the C# side it would be just that simple.

Comment: @lxxtacoxxl -- it makes me very worried for your security -- anyone who would think SP is less secure is quite clueless.  I expect it is a case of the team you work for not knowing how to use or manage SPs -- just as bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after spending all day working on this, I have finally come up with a solution. I load all the databases into a table variable, then I begin looping through those databases and send back their details to the client. After the database details themselves have been sent to the client via `RAISERROR` I then utilize `sp_executesql` to execute a new sub-query with the current database specified to get the list of tables for processing at the end of the primary. The example below demonstrates the basic structure of this process for others experiencing this issue in the future.

Thank you all once again for your help!

-Jamie

```
DECLARE @LoopCounter INT = 1, @DatabaseCount INT = 0;
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX), @dbName NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @Databases TABLE ( _id INT, _name NVARCHAR(MAX) );
DECLARE @Tables TABLE ( _name NVARCHAR(MAX), _type NVARCHAR(15) );

INSERT INTO @Databases
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name) AS id, name
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name NOT IN ( 'master', 'tempdb', 'msdb', 'model' );

SET @DatabaseCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Databases);

WHILE (@LoopCounter <= @DatabaseCount) BEGIN
    SET @dbName = (SELECT _name FROM @Databases WHERE _id = @LoopCounter);
    SET @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT TABLE_NAME, TABLE_TYPE
                          FROM [' + @dbName + '].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES';
        INSERT INTO @Tables EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
    SET @LoopCounter += 1;
END
```

Answer (score 1):

All the tables are in the meta data you can just do a query against that and join to your list of schemas you want to look at.

```
SELECT tab.name 
FROM sys.tables AS tab
JOIN sys.schemas AS sch on tab.schema_id = sch.schema_id
JOIN dbTemp temp on sch.name = temp.[_name]
```

This returns a list of the table to return back as a result set.

Comment: This returned no results, tried it by itself with still no result. I changed the final JOIN to a where clause comparing the schema name to a specific database name (a couple of them actually).

Comment: just take out the last join and add sch.name to the results... then you will know all the schema names both that you want and don't want.

Answer (score 0):

The statement `USE [@dbName]` takes effect AFTER it is run (usually via the GO statement.

```
 USE [@dbName]
 GO
```

The above 2 lines would make you start using the new Database. You cannot use this in the middle of your SQL or SP.

One other option which you can use is to use the dot notation, i.e., dbname..tablename syntax to query your tables.

[double dot notation post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786049/double-dot-table-qualifier/34786151)

Comment: No database could be found by the name '@dbName'. This is the same with double dot and single dot notations.