# SQL: What does the ".." represent in "common..TABLE_NAME"

Tags: sql, sql-server

Just learning SQL and stumbled across this example I would like clarified.

The example is:

```
common..DELIVERY_TABLE s,
```

I understand that

```
DELIVERY_TABLE
```

is the name of the table

but I am unclear as to what

```
common..
```

and what the

```
s
```

is after the TABLE_NAME

I know a SQL statement written as

```
id.DELIVERY_TABLE
```

refers to the id column within the DELIVERY_TABLE

Clarifying this would be a great help.  thanks

UPDATE*** 
(sql statement)

```
SELECT s.LOC_ID, s.SCHEDULE_ROUTE_ID, e.IDENT_ASSET_NUM
FROM common..DELIVERY_TABLE s
WHERE rc.ROUTE_ID = s.SCHEDULE_ROUTE_ID
```

Comment: Can you share the complete statement, and not just a small snippet?

Comment: Is this about MySQL or SQL Server? Please tag accordingly.

Comment: In  SQL SERVER you can use Db_name..Object_Name instead Db_name.dbo.Object_Name

Comment: @MattClark Just provided the complete statement

Comment: @Alejandro I am using RapidSQL and i have corrected my tags.  My apologies.

Comment: @Adrew RapidSQL is not a database, it's just an IDE. Tag with the appropriate DB engine you're using.

Comment: @Alejandro It was SQL SERVER.  My apologies still learning.

Comment: May be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786049/double-dot-table-qualifier/34786151

Comment: thank you @BenM that definitely helped me understand better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`common..DELIVERY_TABLE s`

The complete four parts to locate a object is `SERVER.DATABASE.SCHEMA.OBJECTNAME`

`SERVER` could be omitted if you are in the current server,

`Database` could be omitted if you are in the current databse,

`Schema` could be omitted if you know your default schema name is `DBO`

so for the above: is just `common(database name).DBO(schema name).DELIVERY_TABLE`,

for the last `s` is just the alias your gave to your table for the later join, but I would recommend using `as s` for easier read

Comment: @Adrew, YW! GLAD TO HELP YOU