# oracle sql - using double ampersand (&&) and double dot (..)

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm new to Oracle SQL. I came across the following statement:

```
CREATE TABLE &&DATABASE_ONE..TABLE_ONE(...);
```

The statement above is trying to create a table. I'm not sure if I have correct understanding on `..` and `&&`.

I have done some Googling, I found out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786049/double-dot-table-qualifier/34786151) that says double dot(..) will choose the `default schema` for the query.
`DATABASE_ONE` should be the schema name, and `TABLE_ONE` should be the table name.

I'm confused of using `&&` in front of the database name. After Googling, I found out some posts say that `&&` means `"Oracle will prompt the user for a value and will create a permanent variable"`.

Could someone explain how `&&` works in the statement above? Please correct me if I have any misunderstanding.

Comment: The question you linked to is about SQL Server; the answers there aren't relevant for Oracle. (And `DATABASE_ONE` is the *schema* name, not the database name.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Gary_W has covered the difference between [a single and a double ampersand](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#sthref462).

The double period is perhaps slightly less obvious. From [the SQL*Plus documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#sthref452):

> If you wish to append characters immediately after a substitution variable, use a period to separate the variable from the character.

If you had a single period:

```
&&DATABASE_ONE.TABLE_ONE
```

then that period would be treated as the terminator for the substituion variable name, and would be consumed in the process. Say the value you entered was 'HR'; the substitution would be:

```
old:select &&DATABASE_ONE.TABLE_ONE from dual
new:select HRTABLE_ONE from dual

select HRTABLE_ONE from dual
```

As you can see, there is now no period between the schema and table names, giving you a combined identifier which will not represent what you intended.

With the form you have:

```
&&DATABASE_ONE..TABLE_ONE
```

the second period is the 'normal' one that sits between those two elements; once the first has been consumed by the substitution, the second remains to fulfil that function:

```
old:select &&DATABASE_ONE..TABLE_ONE from dual
new:select HR.TABLE_ONE from dual

select HR.TABLE_ONE from dual
```

Answer (score 2):

The double ampersand will prompt once and everywhere that variable is used it will use what was entered.  If it had only one ampersand, you would get a prompt for every occurrence.

Try it yourself by creating a dummy script with multiple prompts for the same variable.  First use single ampersands, note how it works then switch to double ampersands.

This link has a good explanation: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/oracle-sqlplus-the/1565925785/ch04s02.html